# Undefined type 'Auth' in Laravel routes Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, intelephense

[image: laravel>routes>web.php file in visual studio code IDE]

I'm new to Laravel. The Visual Studio code shows an error on my Laravel project `laravel>routes>web.php` file but the program runs fine without any errors.

Any explanation on how this works?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this code in your **routes/web.php** file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Or just use:

```
use Auth;
```

Comment: or just `use Auth;`